# Problem with your own listview caused by setting values ​in TextView

Tags: java, android

After pressing the button, I go to `SecondActivity`, enter the data, and then after pressing the button I return to `MainActivity`. I create an object in the `onActivityResult` method and then assign it to the object array. I send array with objects to the adapter. Unfortunately, when I try to enable the application, I get the message: ***"app has stopped".***

I do not receive any messages related to errors, but I noticed that the application does not work because of these lines of code. 
Because when I delete them, the application turns on, what could I change in these lines of code?:

```
 holder.nameProduct.setText(object.name); //THIS LINE ???
 holder.priceProduct.setText(String.valueOf(object.price));//THIS LINE ???
```

Below I attach the whole code:

***MainActivity***:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView listView;
    Button button_secondActivity;
    TextView textView_totalPrice;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    static int indexArray = 0;

    Item items [] = new Item[10];

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button_secondActivity = findViewById(R.id.button);
        textView_totalPrice = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        listView = findViewById(R.id.itemsList);

        button_secondActivity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        });




        RowAdapter adapter = new RowAdapter(this, R.layout.row_element, items);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent i) {
        if ((requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) && (resultCode == RESULT_OK)) {

            String nameProduct = i.getStringExtra("nameProduct");
            int priceProduct = i.getIntExtra("priceProduct", 0);

            Item item = new Item(priceProduct, nameProduct);

            items[indexArray] = item;

            indexArray++;
        }
    }
}
```

***SecondActivity***:

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText editText_priceProduct, editText_nameProduct;
    Button button_enterData;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        editText_priceProduct = findViewById(R.id.editText);
        editText_nameProduct = findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        button_enterData = findViewById(R.id.button2);

        button_enterData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                finish();
            }
        });
    }

     public void finish() {

        String nameProduct;
        int priceProduct;

        nameProduct = editText_nameProduct.getText().toString();
        priceProduct = Integer.parseInt(editText_priceProduct.getText().toString());

        Intent i = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("nameProduct", nameProduct);
        i.putExtra("priceProduct", priceProduct);

        setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
        super.finish();

     }
}
```

***Adapter***:

```
public class RowAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {

    Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;
    Item items[] = null;

    public RowAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, Item items []) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, items);

        this.context = context;
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View view = convertView;
        ItemsHolder holder = null;

        if(view == null) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            view = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new ItemsHolder();
            holder.nameProduct =  view.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            holder.priceProduct = view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

            view.setTag(holder);
        }

        else {

            holder = (ItemsHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        Item object = items[position];
        holder.nameProduct.setText(object.name); //THIS LINE ???
        holder.priceProduct.setText(String.valueOf(object.price));//THIS LINE ???


        return view;
    }
}



class ItemsHolder {

    TextView nameProduct, priceProduct;
}
```

***Item***:

```
public class Item {

    int price;
    String name;

    public Item(int price, String name) {
        this.price = price;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following edits and reply me:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    ItemsHolder holder;
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    view = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
    holder = new ItemsHolder();
    holder.nameProduct =  view.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    holder.priceProduct = view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    Item object = items[position];
    holder.nameProduct.setText(object.getName());
    holder.priceProduct.setText(String.valueOf(object.getPrice()));
    return view;
}
```

Comment: An identical message appeared. The problem is that when the application loads, the 'items' array has no objects. So in the getView method the reference variable 'object' does not point to any object, and at the same time I try to assign to TextView the value 'object.name' where object is null. I do not know how I could modify the code to get around this.

Comment: @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }// Add this in adapter and try